# Is it possible to ignore all members of a module in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to implement a argument type checker. I've read several times about Python and Duck typing, but I'm tired of hunting bugs when I could easily enforce the type of inputs for my functions.

My plan is to implement a type checker that right after the function definition, receives the inputs and does its assertion job.

Something like this

```
import sanity_check
fun1(a,b):
    sanity_check.fun1(a,b)
    <do something>

fun2(a,b):
    sanity_check.fun2(a,b)
    <do something>
```

It is not my intention for this type checker to clearly estate what is checking (that is left for the comments on the functions), but just to enforce types.

My idea would be that after implementation, I can erase this sanity check module by just automatically erase all lines with the "sanity_check" word. So, it is not intended permanent use, just during implementation.

Onto my question. I do not want to be constantly erasing and copying back these lines whenever I want to test for real the code, since given the nature of the codes I'm implementing, I know the function call overhead will make significant delays on my codes.

Is it there a way to ignore all the members of this "sanity_check" module?

Setting all the members to None could be a way, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Just an FYI, Python has basic static type checking via Type Hints if you use a competent IDE.

Comment: Yes, you're really looking for *type annotations* and a static type checker. Perhaps some `assert` statements sprinkled in. What you're proposing here is an insane approach for exactly the reasons you mention.

Comment: And as for your question, it would likely be easier to internally toggle the behavior of your functions instead; something like what's common with debugging messages and a global `DEBUG` flag that gets checked constantly.

Comment: I'm using vim, so I do not have these type checkings. But, I do not just want to check specific types, but also numpy array sizes or mixed families of lists.

Comment: You can run a static type checker over your code independently of your Python and/or editor.

Comment: About toggling, I've also thought about it, but I'm aware that just calling a function in Python has a significant overhead cost. This is why I thought of a way to just ignore. I could also insert an "if DEBUG, else sanity_check.fun1" statement, but I neither want to clutter the code.

Comment: Note that Python has the ``__debug__`` constant and ``-O`` flag, which *statically* adds/removes blocks protected by ``if __debug__:``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a combination of type annotations with a static type checker like mypy, plus some [`assert` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement):

> Assert statements are a convenient way to insert debugging assertions into a program [..] The current code generator emits no code for an `assert` statement when optimization is requested at compile time.

You can use this to make runtime checks in debug mode and choose to run your code using the `-O` flag to omit `assert` statements and get maximum performance.

Static type hints can catch other types of problems without incurring (significant) runtime overhead; see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#function-signatures-and-dynamic-vs-static-typing.

Example:

```
def foo(bar: list):
    assert len(bar) >= 3, 'List must be at least 3 long, got %d' % len(bar)
    ...
```

mypy will help you find bugs where you're not even passing a list into `foo`, while the `assert` statement will warn you at runtime if the list is too short, and the check can be omitted if you run the code via `python -O foo.py`.

Comment: Indeed, but simultaneously I want to unclutter the code. Mypy would make a bit too much noise on it. But this assertion option is a good one, I would nonetheless implement this sanity_checker as

"assert sanity_check.fun1(a,b)"

and inside the sanity_check.fun1 function do all the computations that will be ignored with the -o flag. 

Thank you !

Comment: 1. Type hints "add noise", yes, but they also add a ton of information and make function signatures more readable in that they take the guesswork out of what arguments the function accepts exactly. 2. I find inline `assert` statements also add a level of self-documentation. `assert len(bar) >= 3` adds a ton of information when reading the code, and the following custom error message can add even more. You're also not avoiding the function call overhead if you're hiding all this in some generically named "sanity_checker".

Comment: Oh, I thought that by hiding it into a sanity_checker, but inserting it into an assert line, I would hide the function call overhead. If not, this solution is not working for me. 
----
 The issue is that I'm not checking simple statements. I prefer to document the domain and codomain of the functions, but the real computation leave it in a single line. The whole checker function would be at least 15 lines long.

Comment: Well, if you do `assert sanity_checker()`, then yeah, the entire statement will be omitted in `-O` mode. But if you just do `sanity_checker()` with `assert` statements inside it, that will still incur the call to that function.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I wrote in my first reply. 
That works just as I need it.